# cmu sphinx4 java - Runtime exception caused by FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, runtimeexception, sphinx4

I have recently made a Java project with Sphinx4. I found [this](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/dialog/DialogDemo.java) code online, and I slimmed it down to this to test if Sphinx4 was working:

```
public class App 
{
    private static final String ACOUSTIC_MODEL =
            "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us";
    private static final String DICTIONARY_PATH =
            "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setAcousticModelPath(ACOUSTIC_MODEL);
        configuration.setDictionaryPath(DICTIONARY_PATH);

        configuration.setGrammarName("dialog");
        LiveSpeechRecognizer jsgfRecognizer =
                new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

        jsgfRecognizer.startRecognition(true);

        while (true) {

            String utterance = jsgfRecognizer.getResult().getHypothesis();

            if (utterance.startsWith("hello")) {
                System.out.println("Hello back!");
            }
            else if (utterance.startsWith("exit")) {
                break;
            }
        }

        jsgfRecognizer.stopRecognition();
    }
}
```

However, it gave me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Allocation of search manager resources failed
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.allocate(WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:247)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.AbstractDecoder.allocate(AbstractDecoder.java:103)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.allocate(Recognizer.java:164)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer.startRecognition(LiveSpeechRecognizer.java:47)
    at com.weebly.controllingyourcomputer.bartimaeus.App.main(App.java:27)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.language.ngram.SimpleNGramModel.open(SimpleNGramModel.java:403)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.language.ngram.SimpleNGramModel.load(SimpleNGramModel.java:277)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.language.ngram.SimpleNGramModel.allocate(SimpleNGramModel.java:114)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.LexTreeLinguist.allocate(LexTreeLinguist.java:334)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.allocate(WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:243)
    ... 4 more
```

I thought it might be something about it not being able to find the paths for ACOUSTIC_MODEL or DICTIONARY_PATH, so I changed the `resource:` strings to things like `%HOME%\\Downloads\\sphinx4-5prealpha-src\\sphinx4-5prealpha-src\\sphinx4-data\\src\\main\\resources\\edu\\cmu\\sphinx\\models\\en-us` or paths with forward slashes or with `C:\Users\Username\...` but none of the paths worked. I know the paths exist because I copy and pasted them from the properties window of the actual resources.

So my question is: is it some of the code that I deleted from the original source code that is causing this error, is it something wrong with the paths, or is it entirely different?

**EDIT**

By the way, I am using Maven to build my project. I added the dependencies specified on the Sphinx4 website to my pom.xml, but it didn't work (it didn't recognize imports such as `edu.com.sphinx.xxx`) so I downloaded the JARs from the website they said to download them from and added them to my projects "Libraries" in my Java Build Path in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it some of the code that I deleted from the original source code that 
>   is causing this error

Yes, you deleted too much.

To recognize with grammar you need to make three calls:

```
    configuration.setGrammarPath(GRAMMAR_PATH);
    configuration.setGrammarName(GRAMMAR_NAME);
    configuration.setUseGrammar(true);
```